# Exception not being caught in try-except block during unit test

Tags: python, exception, mocking

I have this in my code:

```
import api

def do_something():
    try:
        api = api.Api()
        api.call()
    except ParseException as e:
        logger.exception('Error occurred')
        raise ValidationError(detail=e.message)
```

Basically it calls an API and re-raises the exception with another type.
My test checks the case when the exception is thrown:

```
@patch('code.api')
def test_exception(self, api_mock):
    api_mock.Api.side_effect = ParseException('General Error')
    self.assertRaises(
        ValidationError,
        do_something
    )
    api_mock.Api.assert_called_once()
```

However my test fails because `ParseException` gets thrown and not `ValidationError`. What is going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note the `@patch('code.api')` line. This says patch EVERYTHING in `code.api`. The `ParseException` is probably in the `api` module too and thus patched too. If you debug your code you'll see that `type(ParseException)` is not an instance of Exception but an instance of `MagicMock`.

I just spent an hour banging my head on the desk, hope this helps someone.